# Order a dictionary based on specific values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Before writing a function, I would like to be sure there is no pre-built (optimized) solution (like sorted()) that can:

From a dictionary like this one :

```
tags = {'pinoyako':{'likes': 119, 'comments': 11, 'count': 1}, 'dii':{'likes': 151, 'comments': 3, 'count': 1},'djiphantom3':{'likes': 127, 'comments': 6, 'count': 1}}
```

Order the keys based on 'likes', 'comments' or 'count'. If it's based on 'likes', the output should be a list ordered :

```
output = [['dii',151],['djiphantom3',127],['pinoyako',119]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) within `sorted()` function with a proper key function:

```
In [22]: from operator import itemgetter
In [23]: sorted(((k, v['likes']) for k, v in tags.items()), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
Out[23]: [('dii', 151), ('djiphantom3', 127), ('pinoyako', 119)]
```

Comment: seconds before me, or here's a function: `def my_sort(dct,name): return sorted([[k,v[name]] for k,v in dct.items()], key = itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`

Comment: Clear,Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need more entries to illustrate. Check this:

```
tags = {'pinoyako':{'likes': 119, 'comments': 11, 'count': 1},
        'pinoyako2':{'likes': 120, 'comments': 5, 'count': 2},
        'djiphantom32':{'likes': 1275, 'comments': 61, 'count': 15},
        'dii2':{'likes': 151, 'comments': 33, 'count': 13},
        'dii':{'likes': 151, 'comments': 3, 'count': 1},
        'djiphantom3':{'likes': 1275, 'comments': 61, 'count': 1}
        }
tags_sorted = sorted(tags.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1]['likes'], x[1]['comments'], x[1]['count']))
tags_sorted
```

Output:

```
[('pinoyako', {'comments': 11, 'count': 1, 'likes': 119}),
 ('pinoyako2', {'comments': 5, 'count': 2, 'likes': 120}),
 ('dii', {'comments': 3, 'count': 1, 'likes': 151}),
 ('dii2', {'comments': 33, 'count': 13, 'likes': 151}),
 ('djiphantom3', {'comments': 61, 'count': 1, 'likes': 1275}),
 ('djiphantom32', {'comments': 61, 'count': 15, 'likes': 1275})]
```

Then you can do this:

```
tags_sorted = [[k, v['likes']] for k,v in tags_sorted]
tags_sorted
```

Output:

```
[['pinoyako', 119],
 ['pinoyako2', 120],
 ['dii', 151],
 ['dii2', 151],
 ['djiphantom3', 1275],
 ['djiphantom32', 1275]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting but it is not the output i am looking for.

Comment: @YassineBelmamoun `"Order the keys based on 'likes', 'comments' or 'count'"`?

Comment: Oh I took it as `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: How can you sort based on 3 different criteria ? I am interested.

Comment: @YassineBelmamoun I just did. You can see how it can be done.

Comment: I am not sure i got it : Are you ordering based on the sum of likes+comments+posts ? (talking about the first output before the edit)

Comment: @YassineBelmamoun No. First sort by likes, if the likes are same then sort by comments and if the likes and comments are same then sort by counts.